# Returning json in Wiremock using JSONPath based on attribute value

Tags: json, jsonpath, wiremock

I'm trying to do stubbing with Wiremock to provide a response based upon the body that is sent in the post request.

For example, when sending this json:

```
{
    "person": {
        "firstName": "paul",
        "age": "50"
    }
}
```

I want to send pauldata.json

This is my request/ response json below:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/api/test1",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "matchesJsonPath": "$.person[?(@.firstName=='paul')]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "pauldata.json",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

However this results in an error:

> JSON path expression '$.person[?(@.firstName=='paul')]' failed to match document because of error 'net.minidev.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.util.List

this expression: $.person[?(@.firstName=='paul')] matches the json with the Jayway implementatin at http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/, but not the Goessner implementation which Wiremock uses.

I noticed that if I just do $.person.firstName in jayway it returns "paul",
but when I do the same thing in Goessner I get ["paul"].

How can I match on the value of key using the Goessner implementation of JSONPath so I can return a custom json based on the value of a key in my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WireMock does not accept all JSONPath expressions, although they do work in online testers. I had the same problem, and solved it using the following:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/api/test1",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "matchesJsonPath": "$..[?(@.firstName=='paul')]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "pauldata.json",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

The only thing that changed is from:

```
$.person[?(@.firstName=='paul')]
```

To:

```
$..[?(@.firstName=='paul')]
```

This is because .. notation searches through all input recursively.

In case you need to query a root element, meaning one that doesn't have a parent element, the same JSONPath will do. For example, imagine you have another element like so:

```
{
    "person": {
        "firstName": "paul",
        "age": "50"
    },
    "test": "true"
}
```

In case you want to match for "test": "true" you would need JSONPath as follows:

```
$..[?(@.test=='true')]
```

I tested everything in my WireMock so it should work.